# Default value for `localeDetection`

Tags: reactjs, next.js

What is the default value for `localeDetection`, is it `false`? Based on what I read from [source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/packages/next/build/index.ts#L340), I assume it is false?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `?` means that the property is optional, sometimes it will be there and others not. When the it's not there (`undefined`), the default value is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is 'No'. locale detection is enabled by default as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#automatic-locale-detection) but you can easily disable this feature from next.config.js like this:

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    localeDetection: false,
  },
}
```